# Travis CI testing AngularJS directive with Karma/Jasmine/PhantomJS results in "undefined is not a function"

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner, travis-ci

I'm unit testing an AngularJS directive using Karma/Jasmine/PhantomJS stack and have all successes locally, but when I run it on Travis CI it results in errors:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) test description... FAILED
    TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'angular.element(directiveInput).val('').trigger('input')') in test/tests.spec.js (line 63)
```

Here is my .travis.yml file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"
before_script:
  - npm install -g gulp-cli
  - npm install -g bower
  - bower install
script:
  - gulp test
os: linux
```

And the Gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var Server = require('karma').Server;
gulp.task('test', function(done) {
    new Server({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done).start();
});
```

I tried commenting out the code that throws the error, just to see if that'd give some insight into what's going on. It resulted in a different error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) test description... FAILED
    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ in test/tests.spec.js (line 34)
```

With that in mind I think it may have something to do with jQuery, but I don't really know how Travis CI works. Any help would be appreciated.